# How to start my startup in the following scenario?

Tags: startup

I am a computer science graduate. I have a startup idea which is totally of mechanical domain. Since I do not have enough money to find my startup I am seeking for incubation in one of the college in my city. But inorder to be get the incubator they are asking for a at least the mathematical proof of the working of my machine.

As mechanical engineering is not my expertise I may miss some of the vital concepts in case I do the calculations.

I could have hired a freelancer but they are asking for payment which I am unable to provide as right now I am not earning from my product.

Is there any way by which I could deal this situation or any site on which people help through all of the calculation part?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because here we are dealing with workplace issues not help with starting a business.

Comment: This is not a starting a business question. This is a situation that many of other people must have been facing daily and if a person is not able to start his startup then what is the point of dealing with workplace issues. I am only asking for opinion nothing else.

Comment: And its still off topic here, check out [tour]

Comment: What did the bank say when you tried to get a loan?

Comment: @Tank If you can't even show your "product" works on *paper* then you don't have a product. You have an "idea". If you want to progress this further and you have no funds to pay for someone to do the calculations for you then it's probably time to go back to school, or at least start some learning of the necessary engineering knowledge. Either way you're a long way from actually having  a startup.

Answer (score 4):

**You're trying to bypass one of the critical elements to a startup: self-investment.**  In other words, putting in some of your own money.

Why is this important?

Consider it from an investor's standpoint.  Which would you rather invest in:

- "Well, I've got an idea for making a better elevator.  I don't have a
  working prototype, proof on concept, or even any design analysis that
  says it will work."
- "Well, I've got an idea for making a better elevator.  I hired a
  mechanical engineer, and we developed a proof of concept.  I've also
  received a patent for the design."

The second one, obviously.  It's far lower risk, compared to the, "Well, I have this idea..." pitch.

If your objection is, "But I don't have any money to put into this" or "I don't want to risk my own money"... that doesn't matter to the investor.  In fact, the investor would *much* rather you have money on the line as well, as it helps incentivize you to make sure the project launches!

Answer (score 1):

Do the calculations yourself. See where they go. Don't hide behind the hypothetical "I may miss" something.

Find partners that complement you, that can do what you cannot.

Bring a team to the incubator.

Comment: "`Bring a team to the incubator`" - and forge the "`it's my idea, I want 100%`" mentality - 100% of nothing is not worth as much as 50% (or less) of something